# spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j breaks my project with Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration error

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a working IntelliJ project which uses spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE. When I add the single line

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j")
```

to build.gradle, the project breaks with

> Error creating bean with name 'neo4jAuditionBeanFactoryPostProcessor':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;

I would appreciate any suggestions for how to successfully add neo4j to my project.

I have tried adding

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
runtime("org.neo4j:neo4j:3.4.9")
testCompile("org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver")
compile("org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver")
```

without success.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.3.
I am able to successfully build and run the Spring Getting-Started guide for "Accessing Data with Neo4j", at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/
The only dependency in its build.gradle file is

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j")
}
```

Since that builds successfully, why doesn't adding this single dependency work when I add it to my project?

The complete WARNing message is:

> 2018-12-20 13:51:31.323  WARN 13440 --- [           main]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext :
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'neo4jAuditionBeanFactoryPostProcessor':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/neo4jNeo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory]:
>   Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception;
>   nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
        classpath('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'automentor'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser'
    compile 'javax.json:javax.json-api:1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'fluent-hc', version: '4.5.6'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
    compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.3'
    compile "org.glassfish:javax.json:1.1"
    compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.2.0"
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser'
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.3")
    compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'

    runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator")
}

bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
    systemProperties.remove("java.endorsed.dirs")
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    environment SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: environment.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE ?: "local"
}
```

Comment: Would you please add your main application class and configuration classes? When I use your build file and remove everything JPA and MySQL and add some Neo4j entities, it works fine.

We had some problems with clashing beans in that release, but as it looks, doesn't apply here without more information.

Apart from that: You might ran into problems mixing different stores in the same project. 
And: Commons-fileupload is not needed.

Comment: Sorry, after a month of waiting, I had to give up with this approach and move on.